# UIスライダを実装し音量を調整したい

Tags: swift4

現在教本の内容を元に拡張機能(UIスライダの音源の音量調整)
を実装しようとしています。

解決したい課題としては、現在音楽を再生(play()メソッドを実行)してから音量を調整することはできるのですが、
音楽再生する前にスライダで音量を調整しようとすると「Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)」というエラーが出てきて処理が止まってしまいます。

半日かけてエラー解決に取り組んだのですが現状の自分の知識では解決の糸口が見えないため
質問させて頂きました。
どなたかご教示頂けると幸いです。

コードは下記に転載します。
足りない情報があれば追記致します。

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func prepareToPlay() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //シンバルの音源ファイル指定
    let  cymbalPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("cymbal.mp3")
    //シンバル用のプレイヤーインスタンスを生成
    var cymbalPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    //ギターの音源ファイル指定
    let  guitarPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("guitar.mp3")
    //シンバル用のプレイヤーインスタンスを生成
    var guitarPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    //バック音楽の音源ファイル指定
    let  backMusicPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("backmusic.mp3")
    //バック音楽のプレイヤーインスタンスを生成
    var backMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func cymbal(_ sender: Any) {
        soundPlayer(player: &cymbalPlayer, path: cymbalPath, count: 0)
    }

    @IBAction func guitar(_ sender: Any) {
            soundPlayer(player: &guitarPlayer, path: guitarPath, count: 1)
        }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        soundPlayer(player: &backMusicPlayer, path: backMusicPath, count: -1)
    }

    //    stopボタンがタップされた時の処理
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
           soundPlayer(player: &backMusicPlayer, path: backMusicPath, count: 0)
            backMusicPlayer.stop()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var volume: UISlider!

    @IBAction func volumeController(_ sender: UISlider) {

        backMusicPlayer.volume = volume.value
    }

    //共通のプレイヤー再生処理
    fileprivate func soundPlayer(player:inout AVAudioPlayer,path:URL, count:Int) {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path, fileTypeHint: nil)
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print("エラーが発生しました！")
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: 関数`slidePlayer(...)`が、`ViewController`クラスの実装の中、どこにも使われていませんが、それは間違いありませんか？もし、質問者さんが「解決の糸口が見えない」とおっしゃっているソースコードと、ご提示のコードが、同一のものでないというのでしたら、提示コードを修正してください。おそらく、同一でない箇所に、問題を引き起こしている何かが潜んでいるものと推測されます。

Comment: nagonsoftwareさん、ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたコードは不要なコードだったため削除いたしました。もう少し試行錯誤してみます。

Comment: でしたら、問題の原因は、質問者さんの`AVAudioPlayer`クラスの振る舞いに対する誤解と、Swiftとオブジェクト指向における、参照型と値型の違いについての、誤った理解にあると、ほぼ特定できるようになりましたので、その方向で回答を書いてみたいと思います。いうまでもないかもしれませんが、誤った理解をしているのは、質問者さん自身でなく、質問者さんが勉強のテキストとしている「現在教本の内容を元に」の、教本の執筆者かもしれません。独学でプログラミングの勉強をなさる場合は、学習の対象を複数にして、客観的な情報を選択する、そしてSwiftとiOSの開発に限定するなら、おおもとのAppleが提供する情報（それはXcodeのヘルプから、容易に取得可能です）に、つねにあたる姿勢が必要になるでしょう。

Comment: 色々とありがとうございます。プログラミング学習をする上で、教本を鵜呑みにせず公式ドキュメントを参照する大切さを知りました。参照型と値型について学習します。また何かあればよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

現在あなたが掲載されているコードからわかる、最悪のポイントはこの3行です。

```
    var cymbalPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    var guitarPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    var backMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

各文はインスタンスプロパティを宣言する構文で、それを`AVAudioPlayer()`で初期化しています。ところが、引数なしの`AVAudioPlayer.init()`というイニシャライザの挙動は[Appleの`AVAudioPlayer`公式ドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer)では全く触れられていません。

つまり **`AVAudioPlayer()`と言う構文で作られたインスタンスがどんな動作をするのかについては何の保証もありません**。Appleのドキュメントはお世辞にも十分とは言えませんので、ドキュメント化が不十分な機能を使わざるを得ない場合もあるのですが、少なくとも`AVAudioPlayer`の場合には、**`AVAudioPlayer()`と言う構文を使ってはいけません**。

大昔は知りませんが、少なくとも4〜5年前からのiOSでは、**`AVAudioPlayer()`で作られたインスタンスにどんなメソッドを実行させようとしても、必ずアプリがクラッシュする** と言う動作をします。

---

修正方法ですが、そもそもが、**プロパティ宣言の時に適切なインスタンスを作成できないのであれば、無理に変なインスタンスを作らずに`Optional`型を使うべき** です。そうすれば、コードの他の部分では値が`nil`かそうでないかで、「適切なインスタンスを作成する前」かどうかを判定することができます。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //...(変更のないところ省略)

    //シンバルの音源ファイル指定
    let  cymbalPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("cymbal.mp3")
    //シンバル用のプレイヤー用プロパティ
    var cymbalPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? //<-

    //ギターの音源ファイル指定
    let  guitarPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("guitar.mp3")
    //シンバル用のプレイヤー用プロパティ
    var guitarPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? //<-

    //バック音楽の音源ファイル指定
    let  backMusicPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("backmusic.mp3")
    //バック音楽のプレイヤー用プロパティ
    var backMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? //<-

    @IBAction func cymbal(_ sender: Any) {
        soundPlayer(player: &cymbalPlayer, path: cymbalPath, count: 0)
    }

    @IBAction func guitar(_ sender: Any) {
        soundPlayer(player: &guitarPlayer, path: guitarPath, count: 1)
    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        soundPlayer(player: &backMusicPlayer, path: backMusicPath, count: -1)
    }

    //    stopボタンがタップされた時の処理
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: Any) {
        //↓止める時に新しいプレーヤーを割り当てる必要はない
        //soundPlayer(player: &backMusicPlayer, path: backMusicPath, count: 0)
        backMusicPlayer?.stop() //<-
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var volume: UISlider!

    @IBAction func volumeController(_ sender: UISlider) {

        backMusicPlayer?.volume = volume.value //<-
    }

    //共通のプレイヤー再生処理
    fileprivate func soundPlayer(player:inout AVAudioPlayer?,path:URL, count:Int) { //<-`AVAudioPlayer`ではなく`AVAudioPlayer?`にしています
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path, fileTypeHint: nil)
            player?.play() //<-
        } catch {
            print("エラーが発生しました！", error) //<-エラーを捨ててしまうとデバッグが困難になる
        }
    }
}
```

どのような「教本」をお使いなのかわかりませんが、`AVAudioPlayer()`なんて構文を直接使っておきながら、上記のような注意事項を全く記載されていないのでしたら、その教本の著者はiOS開発についてそれほど経験を積まれていない可能性が強いので、そのつもりで教本を読んでください。

---

いろいろ試行錯誤されているようなので、上記の修正だけでは足りないかもしれませんが、まずは必要になるはずの事柄です。これだけではうまくいかないとか言うことがあれば、コメント等でお知らせ下さい。

Comment: OOPerさん　コードの修正いただきありがとうございます。意図通りの動作が行えるようになりました。                                                                                                               >少なくとも4〜5年前からのiOSでは、AVAudioPlayer()で作られたインスタンスにどんなメソッドを実行させようとしても、必ずアプリがクラッシュする 　割と評判の良い教本の為、既存コードは疑わなかったのですが甘かったです。今回の経験をバネにOptional型の学習とコードをリファレンスを元に作成する練習をしていきたいと思います、色々とありがとうございました、また何かあればお願いいたします。

Comment: @korokorometal さん、コメントありがとうございます。「評判の良い」と言うことなら、別の部分で良いところがたくさんあるのでしょうが、同じようなコードが蔓延することになるなら大変心配ですね。Optional型をどううまく扱うかと言うのは、Swift言語の学習としてはキモの部分の一つでもあります。Q&Aサイトも活用して、うまく習得できるようお祈りしております。

Comment: ありがとうございます、少しづつ勉強して精進していきます。

Answer (score 1):

※以下、「質問者さんは、こういう誤った理解をしている」という表現をしますが、それに対して、質問者さんがまったく心当たりのない印象を受けるかもしれません。それはおそらく、質問者さんがテキスト（教科書）にしている教本の執筆者が、誤った理解をしているからだということになります。なので、そこらへんは、柔軟に表現を読み替えていただくようお願いします。

質問者さんがおそらくしているであろう、誤った理解は、次の2点が挙げられます。ひとつは、クラス`AVAudioPlayer`に対して。もうひとつは、Swiftならびにオブジェクト指向における、参照型に関するものです。まず、`AVAudioPlayer`クラスに対する誤解についてお話しします。

---

`AVAudioPlayer`という名称から、このクラスは、CDデッキや、Walkman、iPod touchといった携帯音楽プレイヤーのメタファを連想するのではないでしょうか？CDデッキに、ベートーベンの交響曲第九を挿入して、再生ボタンを押したら、第九が再生され、モーツァルトの魔笛のCDを挿入したら、魔笛が再生されるというものです。再生時の音量（Volume）は、CDデッキに設定したものであって、CDを変えるたびに、音量が元に戻ってしまうということは起こりません。
しかし、`AVAudioPlayer`のインスタンスは、そういうものではなく、一つの曲、一つの音声データにつき、ひとつの`AVAudioPlayer`インスタンスが作られます。
[Class AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer)のプロパティ`url`ならびに`data`の項をみてください。`url`については、

```
var url: URL? { get }
```

となっています（`data`も同様）。`{ get }`は、読み出し専用で、書き込み不可のプロパティであることを意味します。（書き込み可能な場合は`{ get set }`という表記となります）
すなわち、CDを交換したら（URL、ファイルパスを変えたら）別の曲が再生されるということではないということがわかります。イニシアライザ`init(contentsOf url: URL)`でURLを指定して、いったんインスタンスを生成したら、後から変更できません。

---

ご提示のコードからは、Swiftならびにオブジェクト指向におけるインスタンスの参照について、正しく理解されているとは思えません。いい機会ですから、Swiftの「クラスという参照型」について、しっかり勉強しましょう。
まず、Swiftでは、参照型のオブジェクトはクラスだけに限定されます。そのほかの、構造体（Structure）、列挙体（Enumeration）などは、参照型でなく値型です。
では、参照型ってなんなの？ですが、まず、以下のコードを、XcodeのPlaygroundで実行しみてください。

```
// クラスHogeの定義
class Hoge {
    var name: String

    var volume: Float = 0

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

// クラスHogeのインスタンス化。
var hoge1 = Hoge(name: "Taro")
hoge1.volume = 100
print(hoge1.volume) // 100

var hoge0 = hoge1 // hoge1の参照を、hoge0に代入。
hoge0.volume = 200
print(hoge1.volume) // 200
// 変数hoge0、hoge1いずれにも、同一のインスタンスの参照が代入されている。
```

変数`hoge0`に対する操作（変更）が、変数`hoge1`に反映される、これが参照型のなせる技なのですが、これだけでは、「だからなんなの？」と思われるかもしれません。しかし、`ViewControllerA`の画面で加えた、ユーザの入力が、`ViewControllerB`の画面のオブジェクト（例えばテーブルとか、コレクションとか）に反映されるメカニズムが、このクラスの参照型で実現できると考えると、使い勝手のあるツールということができます。
ところが、このメカニズムは同時に、あるクラスのインスタンスの参照を代入していた変数に対して、別のクラスのインスタンスの参照を代入すると、代入前のクラスのインスタンスは参照しなくなるということになります。

```
class Hoge {
    var name: String

    var volume: Float = 0

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

var hoge1 = Hoge(name: "Taro")
hoge1.volume = 100
print(hoge1.volume) // 100

var hoge2 = Hoge(name: "Hanako")
hoge2.volume = 50
print(hoge2.volume) // 50

hoge1 = hoge2 // 変数hoge1に、hoge2に代入されている、name="Hanako"のインスタンスの参照を代入
print(hoge1.name) // Hanako
print(hoge1.volume) // 50
```

以上の試行（あるいは実験）から、ご提示のコードは、意図どおりにはまったく動作しないことが、明らかになったと思います。

---

以下、クラスの参照型に関する話から離れて、プログラミングの実践的なアドバイスを、おまけで書いておこうと思います。
まず、`UIViewController`のサブクラスの、初期化処理は、`viewDidLoad()`メソッドに書いてください。そして、プロパティ定義において、デフォルト値を書いて、初期化処理をしたような気になることはやめましょう。
次に、Xcodeのヘルプとして閲覧できる各リファレンスをひととおり見渡して、これから使おうとしているメソッド類より適したものがないか、確認を怠らないようにしましょう。
以下のコードを参考にしてください。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeSlider: UISlider!

    var cymbalPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cymbal", withExtension: "mp3") { // リソース内が、階層化で複雑になっていなければ、リソースファイルをダイレクトに指名できる。
            cymbalPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) // 例外処理の簡易パターンを使用。
            cymbalPlayer?.delegate = self
            if let value = cymbalPlayer?.volume {
                volumeSlider.value = value
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playCymbal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cymbalPlayer?.play() // 初期化処理がちゃんとできていれば、たった1行で再生ができます。
        sender.isEnabled = false // 再生中、ボタンを押せないようにしておく。
    }

    // cymbalPlayer delegate 再生が終了したら、ボタンを押せるように戻す。
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        playButton.isEnabled = true
    }

    // 音量調整
    @IBAction func volumeLebel(_ sender: UISlider) {
        cymbalPlayer?.volume = sender.value
    }
}
```

`AVAudioPlayer`の音源は、たとえばネットワークでダウンロードしたデータや、ミュージックアプリの連携で参照できるファイルのように、やや信頼性の低いものを対象にするため、初期化メソッドが、例外処理を伴うもの（`throws`）になっていますが、アプリのリソースにある音源なら、例外が発生する確率はたいへん低いので、`do - try - catch`構文でなく、簡易構文である`try?`をここでは使っています。（絶対例外は起きないという前提の`try!`構文もあります）
`try?`構文は、例外処理を、Optional Chaining、Optional Bindingに置き換える働きをします。

Comment: nagonsoftwareさん、色々とご教示いただきありがとうございます。AVAudioPlayerのくだりの説明が大変わかりやすく理解を深めることができました。基礎的な文法力と知識が足りていないと感じるので、いただいたコードを元に学習を続けて精進していきます。